# How to find the first time a specific value occurs

Tags: matlab

I have a graph (y=t^2) and I need to find the **first** t value where y > 20

```
t = 0:.01:10;
y = t.^2;
plot(t,y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of `find` will let you specify the number of indices to return.

```
find(y>20, 1)
```

If you want the actual value and not the index, just index array with your result.

```
y(find(y>20, 1)) % first value in y where y>20
t(find(y>20, 1)) % first value in t where y>20
```

Comment: The question was worded strangely in my homework and it's actually asking for the first time (t value) where y>20.

Comment: I updated my response accordingly. You can index into y or t with the result of `find`.

Comment: If you call `find` without defining the number of indices you want returned, it will return all indices that meet your condition. The length of this array is the number of times the condition is met. Alternatively, you can use something like `sum(y>20)`.